# how to fix issue with body-params values not being picked up by clojure muuntaja middleware

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to adapt the code here https://github.com/danownsthisspace/shorturl/blob/main/src/shorturl/core.clj with this:

```
(ns todo.core
  (:require [clojure.pprint :as pprint]
            [muuntaja.core :as m]
            [reitit.ring :as ring]
            [reitit.ring.middleware.muuntaja :as muuntaja]
            [ring.adapter.jetty :as ring-jetty]
            [ring.util.response :as r]
            [todo.db :as db]))

(defn todo-items-save [req]
  (clojure.pprint/pprint req)
  (let [title (get-in req [:body-params :title])
        content (get-in req [:body-params :content])]
    (r/response (str "foooo" title))))
(def app
  (ring/ring-handler
   (ring/router
    [["/"
      ["" {:handler (fn [req] {:body "hello" :status 200})}]]
     ["/api/todo" {:post {:handler todo-items-save}
                   :get (fn [req]
                          (let [todos db/get-todos]
                            (r/response todos)))}]
     {:data {:muuntaja m/instance :middleware [muuntaja/format-middleware]}}])))

(defn start []
  (ring-jetty/run-jetty #'app {:port 3002 :join? false}))
(def server (start))

(.stop server)
```

but I'm seeing that the body-params values are null. I was wondering why that is when I'm making a post request with the body `{"content":"only a test", "title":"second"}`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was, that the muuntaja config was passed as part of the
routes instead of argument to `ring/router`

```clj
(def app
  (ring/ring-handler
   (ring/router
    [["/"
      ["" {:handler (fn [req] {:body "hello" :status 200})}]]
     ["/api/todo" {:post {:handler todo-items-save}
                   :get (fn [req]
                          (let [todos db/get-todos]
                            (r/response todos)))}]]
    ; XXX this must be the second argument to `ring/router`
    {:data {:muuntaja m/instance
            :middleware [muuntaja/format-middleware]}})))
```